# Show code dependant on CPT & category

Tags: custom-post-types, php, slug

I'm currently using the following plugin on my WordPress website to show our up coming events:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-eventbrite-events/

I need to write an IF statement that will check the custom post type and then a category of the post type which will then return my custom code.

So far I've tried the following code:

`if ( is_singular( ‘eventbrite_events’ ) && has_category( ‘network’ ) )`

If I remove the category reference it works, but it will show my custom code on all events pages. Whereas I only want it to show the code in a certain category of the custom post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`has_category` applies only to default `post` type.
You are working on a CPT so you should use [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)

```
if ( is_singular( 'eventbrite_events' ) && has_term( 'network', '{YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY}' ) )
```

where {YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY} is optional and it must be the slug for eventbrite_events taxonomy to which the term 'network' is attached to.